# jmx mbean server throw InstanceAlreadyExistsException when change c3p0 version

Tags: java, spring, jmx, c3p0, mbeans

What are the differences between `c3p0-0.9.1.2` and `c3p0-0.9.5` that mean that when I want to register an `MBean` with `DynamicPooledDataSourceManagerMBean` in `0.9.1.2` everything is okay, but when I use `0.9.5` then `com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository` throws an `javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException`.

I use spring as my container so the bean definition for `DynamicPooledDataSourceManagerMBean` is like this:

```
<bean id="register" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.management.DynamicPooledDataSourceManagerMBean">
   <constructor-arg index="0" ref="dataSource"/>
   <constructor-arg index="1" value="my.pool.connection:type=c3p0,name=Main"/>
   <constructor-arg index="2" ref="mbeanServer"/>
</bean>
```

which the dataSource ref definition is a `com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource` and defined like this:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" lazy-init="true" >
        and a lot of datasource config
```

and the `mbeanSever` is a Spring `org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanServerFactoryBean` which is defined like this:

```
<bean name="mbeanServer"
    class="org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanServerFactoryBean">
    <property name="locateExistingServerIfPossible" value="true" />
    <property name="registerWithFactory" value="true"></property>
</bean>
```

Comment: You shouldn't need or want to explicitly register an MBean. c3p0 will try to do it automatically, unless you turn that off with `com.mchange.v2.c3p0.management.ManagementCoordinator=com.mchange.v2.c3p0.management.NullManagementCoordinator`

Comment: where should I put this config?

Comment: The problem here is I need to distinct different MBeans which are exported and c3p0 register them with names like this:
com.mchange.v2.c3p0:type=PooledDataSource,identityToken=1hgeowz961y14x0ldebkgx|123f9b8,name=Main

How can i give it a name and prevent adding identittyToken?

Comment: That config would go in a c3p0.properties file or as a System property, most commonly. (It could also go in a HOCON/typesafe-config file if you are using those.) You might (or might not!) be able to get your existing configuration to work by turning off c3p0's autoregistration of MBeans as above, using `com.mchange.v2.c3p0.management.ManagementCoordinator=com.mchange.v2.c3p0.manage‌​ment.NullManagementCoordinator` See http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#jmx_configuration_and_management

Comment: But, much more safely and sanely, consider letting c3p0 just register its MBeans as intended. You can set the name for your MBean via the dataSourceName property (which itself can be set via a Constructor argument or as an ordinary bean property). If you don't want the identity token to appear in the JMX name, set (again in c3p0.properties or as a System property) `com.mchange.v2.c3p0.management.ExcludeIdentityToken=true` (But then it will be your responsibility to ensure JMX names are always unique.) Again, see http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#jmx_configuration_and_management

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, as @SteveWaldman said, was I tried to register my datasources into MBean server which c3p0 registered them before. So what I should have done was nothing.
But there were some modification need to be done to what c3p0 registed.
c3p0 register datasource with a name like this:

```
com.mchange.v2.c3p0:type=PooledDataSource,identityToken=1hgeowz961y14x0ldebkgx|1‌​23f9b8,name=Main
```

I would like to avoid adding identityToken so as said [here](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#jmx_configuration_and_management) I create a c3p0.properties file and put this line into it:

```
com.mchange.v2.c3p0.management.ExcludeIdentityToken=true
```

That was pretty much everything I had to do for my case. Thanks to @StevenWaldman.